# php get one function varibale into other function in class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying make a wordpress plugin to generate an unique order id for customers. I am doing as below but it is not returning value. My code is here below.

```
class abc {
    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'publish_wpcf7s',   array($this, 'send_mails_on_publish' ), 10, 2);

    }
    function setID() { 

         global $id;
         $a = md5(time());
         echo $id = substr($a,0,8);

    }


    function send_mails_on_publish($post)
    {   
        global $post;
        global $id;

        $price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'quote_price', true );
        $to =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true ); 
        $subject    ="Thank You! Please Pay $price Us For Order No. $id";

        $message    ="message";

        $headers[] = "Disposition-Notification-To: $sender_email\n";
        $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
        $headers[] = 'From: Example ' . "\r\n";
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );


    }       

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you call the `setID()`? Anyway, this code is really smelling.

Check this:

```
class abc {

    private $id = 0;
    private $post;

    function __construct() {
        add_action('publish_wpcf7s', array($this, 'send_mails_on_publish'), 10, 2);
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getPost() {
        return $this->post;
    }

    function setId() {
        $a = md5(time());
        $this->id = substr($a, 0, 8);
    }

    function setPost($post) {
        $this->post = $post;
    }


    function send_mails_on_publish() {
        //do whatever you want.
        $price = get_post_meta($this->post->ID, 'quote_price', true);
        $to = get_post_meta($this->post->ID, 'email', true);
        $subject = "Thank You! Please Pay $price Us For Order No. $this->id";
        //.....
        // do whatever you want
    }

}
```

And when you want to use it:

```
$Abc = new abc();
$Abc->setId();
$Abc->setPost($post);
```

Alternative way, if you pass the `$post` as a parameter to construct your object, and set the `$this->post` there. In this case you do not need the `setPost` method,, but you can keep it if you want to change that, but that is not a good design too.

Answer (score 3):

Define the `$id` property, initialize and then use it inside any of your class methods with `$this`

```
class abc {
    private $id; 

    function setID() {
        $a = md5(time());
        $this->$id = substr($a,0,8);
    }

    function send_mails_on_publish($post) {
        // use `$this->id` instead of `id`
    }
}
```

If you want the `id` property to be generated automatically every time you create the class instance just place it inside `__construct()` method

```
function __construct() {
    $this->setID();
}
```

Comment: hi I followed the instructions of DevDonkey. It is getting the different values on two places. Sorry, I forgot to mention in my question. I want to get the same uniq id in two places. First for database and other for sending email

Comment: Just place `$this->setID();` inside the `__construct()` call like I said and use `$this->$id` anywhere else in your class methods, it wouldn't change if you don't call `$this->setID();` again

Comment: Ok. Let my try.

Comment: Cannot access empty property on line
    function setID() {
        $a = md5(time());
        $this->$id = substr($a,0,8);
    }

Comment: Did you defined it `private $id;` inside your class?

Comment: Yes I define it as private